# Laravel required on pivot validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

How can i do a validation on a array?

here is the validation code:

```
$validation = Validator::make($request->input(), [
            'title' => 'required|max:255'
        ]);
```

here is the validation check:

```
    if ($validation->fails())
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validation->errors());
    }
```

And this is the array it needs to validate:

```
array:1 [▼
  1 => ""
]
```

Note that the key 1 here is needed for multi language.

Im looking forward to a response :)

Answer (score 0):

In order for validation to work you need validation rules keys to match keys in the array that contains data you want to validate. Your validation rules define field called **title**, yet I don't see a **title** field in your data array.

If such array contains subarrays that contain fields like aforementioned *title* that share common structure and validation rules, they way to validate that is to iterate through the base array and to call **Validator::make()->fails()** on each of the subarrays:

```
foreach ($request->input() as $subarray) {
  $validation = Validator::make($subarray, [
    'title' => 'required|max:255'
  ]);

  if ($validation->fails())
  {
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validation->errors());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however someone noticed me i could use validation->each('title', ['required', 'max:255']);

Answer (score 0):

`validation->each('title', ['required', 'max:255']);` was the solution here